# Can we define a data partitioning in K clusters, by cutting the branches of the tree at some levels in the tree below the root node?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-data-format

Assume we have a dendogram (hierarchical clusterisation tree), can we define a data partitioning  in K clusters, by cutting the branches of the tree at some levels in the tree below the root node?

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely, in fact that's exactly how one obtains actual clusters with [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering).

With hierarchical clustering it's possible to decide the number of clusters (i.e. the level of "precision") after obtaining the tree (dendogram).